# Javascript functions isn't acting intuitively

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My Javascript functions isn't acting the way I would expect it to.

```js
function submitDetailsForm() {
  if (this.Attr("value") == "Add") {
    alert("Add");
  }
  alert("Not");
}
```

```html
<button type="button" name="submit" id="remove" value="Remove" onclick="submitDetailsForm()">Remove</button>
<button type="button" name="submit" id="add" value="Add" onclick="submitDetailsForm()">Add</button>
<button type="button" name="submit" id="edit" value="Edit" onclick="submitDetailsForm()">Edit</button>
```

if I run this page (there is more code but it's irrelevant to the question), then I use the add button the "add" alert doesn't go of but neither does the "not" alert. I'm not to bothered about the add alert because it could just be failed syntax but in any case surely the not alert should always fire if the function is run. I am certain the function is running because if i move the not alert to above the if statement it will run. 
Any help would be much Appreciated.

[Resolved]
I resolved the problem by using the idea of passing the object into the function. i also had forgotten to actually declare that i was using JQuery in the script tag.
**Resolved code:**

```
<button type="button" name="submit" id="remove" value="Remove" onclick="submitDetailsForm(this)">Remove</button>
    <button type="button" name="submit"  id="add" value="Add" onclick="submitDetailsForm(this)">Add</button>
    <button type="button" name="submit"  id="edit" value="Edit" onclick="submitDetailsForm(this)">Edit</button>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function submitDetailsForm(obj) {


            if ($(obj).attr("value") == "Add") {
                alert("Add");
            } else {
                alert("Not");
            }


        }
     </script>
```

*

Comment: Open console. What does it says? In which JS documentation did you find the `Attr` method?

Comment: Open your browser's developer tools and look at the console. It's showing you an error message. The console (and dev tools in general) are a vital part of doing web development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Pass this object in the function**

```
<button type="button" name="submit" id="remove" value="Remove" onclick="submitDetailsForm(this)">Remove</button>
<button type="button" name="submit"  id="add" value="Add" onclick="submitDetailsForm(this)">Add</button>
<button type="button" name="submit"  id="edit" value="Edit" onclick="submitDetailsForm(this)">Edit</button>


<script>
    function submitDetailsForm(obj) {


        if (obj.value == "Add") {
            alert("Add");
        } else {
            alert("Not");
        }


    }
 </script>
```